# How to make the taskbar date show the current day of year number?

Tags: windows, taskbar, date, clock

I want the clock / date area within the taskbar to show me the day of year number. E.g. February 1st would be "32" - number would be in the [1..366] range. How can I make it happen?

Comment: Short answer : You can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the later versions of Windows (probably at least Windows 8 and beyond) there is only very limited modification of the primary Windows UI possible.

The time/date in the taskbar is what we'd call "hard coded", that is, it is not a modifiable UI element.

On older versions of Windows, XP and 7 in particular, there were programs such as LiteStep that could replace Explorer.exe and provide alternate primary UIs for Windows. But these have not been developed in many years now as Microsoft has more closely integrated the UI and underlying elements of Windows.

All that to say: You can't do this, and the tools that used to allow you to do things like this don't work any longer.